# How can I perform a strict host key checking using JSch

Tags: ssh, jgit

I am trying to connect to a server using `JGit`. I can connect successfully using the following setting

```
JSch.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
```

The problem is that I actually want a strict host key checking. So I replaced the previous line with the following:

```
JSch.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "yes");
```

But now it doesn't work. My certificates a located in a folder called `.ssh` located in my home directory. The names of the files are `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub`. In the server (that has Linux) I have a file called `authorized_keys` located in `~/.ssh` which has the same content as `id_rsa.pub`.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include all of the relevant code from your program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code was actually ok. The problem is that you have to do the following things:

These operation must be performed on you client computer.

1) Create a folder named `.ssh` in you home directory (for example `C:\Users\John`)

2) Enter the new folder and create the certificates using `git bash` with the following command

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -m PEM
```

The certificates are 2 files named `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub`

3) Type the following command (always using `git bash`):

```
ssh-keyscan -t rsa ip_address_of_your_server >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

It will create a file called `known_hosts`. So eventually in the .ssh folder of the client there will be 3 files: `id_rsa`, `id_rsa.pub` and `known_hosts`. 
Now go to you server computer and do the following

1) Create a folder named .ssh in you home directory (for example `~/John`)

2) Enter there and create a file named `authorized_keys` and copy the content of the file `id_rsa.pub` inside this new file

3) Find the file `etc/ssh/sshd_config`

4) Make sure that the following 2 lines are present and uncommented

```
PubKeyAuthentication yes
PasswordAuthentication no
```

5) Save the file and restart sshd

```
sudo systemctl restart sshd
```